# Word VBA find next comment with specific author - sometimes finds other authors' comments

Tags: vba, comments, ms-word, author

hope someone can help.

I have the following line in my VBA:

```
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToComment, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1, Name:=Last_chosen
```

Last_chosen is an author name taken from a dropdown in a userform, and debug.print shows it is read into the macro correctly.

Problem is that the find works OK a few times, then for some reason it finds a comment that belongs to a different author. Even if there are more comments from the Last_chosen author further down the document. And once this happens, it continues to find the wrong comments, sometimes from more than one author, even though Last_chosen is not changed from the original required author.

I've tried hiding some authors' comments in Review | Show Markup | Reviewers in case there's a glitch (?) when Word defines the author but the VBA still finds the wrong comment sometimes, suggesting that there isn't a glitch.

Thanks all.

Here's all the code.

```
Public Last_chosen As String
Public Form_chosen As Integer

'****************

Sub Next_chosen_comment()
'This is where the user first specifies a new author
'to search for their next comment

Dim Re_peat As String
'Dim Cho_sen As String
Re_peat = "N"
'Cho_sen = ""
Last_chosen = ""
Call Next_chosen(Re_peat, Last_chosen)
End Sub

'****************

Sub Repeat_search_next()
'This is where the user repeats the same search
'i.e. jumps to the next comment of the same author
'without having to choose again from the dropdown
'via the Next_chosen_comment() macro

Dim Re_peat As String
'Dim Cho_sen As String
Debug.Print Last_chosen
Re_peat = "Y"
'Cho_sen = Last_chosen
'Call Next_chosen(Re_peat, Cho_sen)
Call Next_chosen(Re_peat, Last_chosen)
Re_peat = "N"
End Sub

'****************

Sub Next_chosen(Repeat_nxt As String, Last_chosen As String)

If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count < 1 Then
    MsgBox "There are no comments.", vbOKOnly, "********NO COMMENTS********"
    Exit Sub
End If

Debug.Print "Repeat_nxt: " & Repeat_nxt

If Repeat_nxt = "Y" Then ' If this is a repeat search (called from Repeat_search_next() macro)
    GoTo Repeat_next
End If

Comment_dropdown.Show 'Not a repeat search
'so show the userform containing the 8 dropdown values

If Form_chosen = -1 Then 'Cancelled userform
    Exit Sub
End If

Select Case Form_chosen 'Set the author to look for
    Case 0
        Chosen = "Contractions"
    Case 1
        Chosen = log_words"
    Case 2
        Chosen = "US_to_UK"
    Case 3
        Chosen = "Other"
    Case 4
        Chosen = "Spaces"
    Case 5
        Chosen = "Ampersand"
    Case 6
        Chosen = "Duplicate"
    Case 7
        Chosen = "Style"
End Select

Last_chosen = Chosen 'Sets Last_chosen from the dropdown
'in case user wants to subsequently repeat the same find
'using the Repeat_search_next() macro

Repeat_next:

Debug.Print "Last_chosen: " & Last_chosen

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToComment, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1, Name:=Last_chosen
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
    End With
End Sub

'*****************Userform****************

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Drop_down
    .AddItem "Contractions"
    .AddItem "-log words"
    .AddItem "US to UK changes"
    .AddItem "Other changes"
    .AddItem "Multiple spaces"
    .AddItem "Ampersands"
    .AddItem "Duplicate paragraphs"
    .AddItem "Non-RFP styles"
End With
End Sub

'****************

Private Sub OK_btn_Click()
Form_chosen = Drop_down.ListIndex
Unload Me
End Sub

'****************

Private Sub Cancel_btn_Click()
Form_chosen = -1
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: So, Word gets it into its head that `Last_Chosen` is a name which is present but not chosen, and, once convinced that the not chose was chosen sticks to that conviction. There are two possible reasons for this behaviour. One, Word has a bug to the effect that the comments' `Name` property is being associated with the wrong comments. This appears unlikely because comments are a collection and any mix up of collections' `Name` property would be apparent elsewhere as well.

Comment: The other possible reason is that there is a mix up in how the `Last_Chosen` variable is assigned its value. That possibility requires examination of your entire code. I say "entire" because you already looked "everywhere". Therefore it is safe to presume that such an error would hide where you didn't expect to find it. Now, if you prefer to think that the first reason is the cause, we can't help you. And if you wish to consider the second possibility, please enable our help by adding your code to your question.

Comment: @Variatus - thanks for your suggestions - I'll post the code shortly

Comment: @Variatus - Have posted the code. Have also noticed it tends to go wrong on the 12th run of the Repeat_search_next() macro...

Comment: @Variatus
Thanks for your help and suggestions. I've made some changes:
-now no spaces in variable names
-use public variable 'Last_chosen' in the call to the called sub and in the called sub
-kept 'Chosen' in the 'Select Case' section - is this OK?
-kept variable 'Re_peat' in the calls but 'Repeat_nxt' in the called sub - is this OK?
Also, I'm not looking for <words> in the comments, but for comments with a specific <author name> using 'Name:-Last_chosen'
Thanks!

Comment: According to your code you are looking for "Duplicates" (short for "Duplicate paragraphs") anywhere in the comments. Are you sure that the `Name` argument for the search limits the search to the author's name? I researched this point and found MSDN not clear about it. Anyway, do you still have the same problem after the changes? Can you confirm that the search criterion - whether name or "Duplicate" - doesn't occur anywhere in the text of the comments?

Answer (score 0):

On first examination of your code I find the following flaws.

1. You have a public variable `Last_chosen` which is kept aligned with the private variables `Cho_sen` and `Chosen`. I didn't find where these are being confused, but rather than look for such a point I would eliminate the two private variables and work with the public one only. You save a lot of code and eliminate any chance of confusion.
2. You have a private variable named `Repeat`. "Repeat" is a key word reserved for the use of VBA. Select "Repeat" and press F1 for more information. Again, I doubt that this is the source of your problem, but the use of reserved words as variable names can cause unexpected, seemingly unrelated and usually unidentifiable errors. Better to choose another name

My suspicion now falls on another scenario. You are looking for certain words in the comments. What would happen, if the words you are looking for is found in the comment text of another author? In other words, you may need code to ensure that the match found actually represents the name of an author.

Please fix the above two points and comment on my suspicion. If the error still persists thereafter I will hack your code into smaller pieces. :-)

Meanwhile, I suggest that you implement the following simplifications into your code. First, create a function like this one:-

```
Function DD_Items(Optional ByVal Idx As Integer = -1) As Variant

    Dim Fun As Variant                      ' function return value
    Dim Items As String

    Items = "Contractions,-log words,US to UK changes,Other changes,Multiple spaces," & _
            "Ampersands,Duplicate paragraphs,Non-RFP styles"
    Fun = Split(Items, ",")

    If Idx >= 0 Then
        If Idx > UBound(Fun) Then Idx = 0   ' mistaken Idx
        Fun = Fun(Idx)
    End If
    DD_Items = Fun
End Function
```

When you call this function without an argument it will return an array, otherwise the array element specified by the argument. Use this function to load your dropdown.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Drop_down
        .List = DD_Items
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, replace your Select statements with this code.

```
Last_Chosen = DD_Items(Form_Chosen)
```

Comment: thanks for your help and suggestions. I've made some changes:

Comment: You don't need to pass `Last_Chosen` as an argument to your sub-routines. Since it is a `Public` variable, it is available everywhere in that module.

Comment: Sorry, I got interrupted by a phone call. Obviously, if you have one argument `Last_Chosen` and one public variable by the same name VBA should be allowed to revolt. Eliminate the argument, and just use the `Last_chosen` variable in the sub.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I have decided a different route; instead of jumping from one author's comments to the next, I've used the dropdown to allow the user to display only one author's comments at a time. Then another button to jump from one comment to the next (which works fine!). But I'm about to post another question...